# jar files in web-inf/lib not recognized

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans

I am using *netbeans*, after i create new J.S.P project
I did not find the **web-inf/lib** folder so I added it myself.
After that when **I add jar files to it my J.S.P file does not compile at all**!
Help please?

Comment: Sounds like the WEB-INF/lib JARs still aren't in your CLASSPATH.

Comment: JSP-Files wont compile themselfe, do you have a JSP-Server? Tomcat? JBoss? GlassFish? WebLogic?

Comment: you are right but that does not even work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for answering my own question but the problem was I was coding jsp before this time
and i was able to any database connection with out using. `Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");`

Then i just assumed it like an optional and indeed it is with newer version of java and apache tomcat.
But that was not the case today!
including `Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");`
 was mandatory!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using netbeans and want to include jar files for JSP than no need to add lib folder in WEB-INF. Instead of it right click on **Libraries** in the project folder. than click on **Add Jar** and browse upto your jar file and click add.